# Cordova add/remove plugin and platform really slow

Tags: cordova

I'm still using Cordova 7.1.0 at the moment because it has a a "--nofetch" option which is removed in Cordova 8.

Everytime I tried to do plugin add or remove, or platform add or remove, it takes like 2 minutes. (I have 41 plugins and OK I didn't really time it but it's about that long.).

It's fast when I just re-create the project, but when I added the 41 plugins things slow to a crawl.

Removing platform take like 4 to 5 seconds if I do a `--nofetch`. But why is it fetching anything when I'm just trying to remove stuff?! I'm pulling my hair out over this one!

I don't exactly know what's underneath the hood.

**EDIT**

Don't know why I get marked down for it. The issue is very real. I did re-create the whole project with the same Cordova platform and it is much speedier.

Comment: same problem here.